# Mover una imagen en pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Hola quería que una imagen se moviera sola atreves de la pantalla hacia abajo así

```
def pintarobot():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    velocidady = 1
    while y != 352:
        Panta.blit(aSprt[5],(x,y))
        y = y + velocidady
```

Pero queda con una estela atras, mas como si lo hubiera pintado muchas veces y no hubiera movido la imagen

Edición: Este es como quedo despues de lo que me comentaron, pero no me funciono, queda una imagen al inicio y otra al final

```
def pintarobot():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    velocidady = 1
    while y != 352:
        Pinta_Mapa() #Pense que se referian a esto pero quiza quedo mal? 
        Panta.blit(aSprt[5],(x,y))
        y = y + velocidady
# Mapa
#mapa a pintar
mapa = [
    [8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7, 1],
]

#Va recorriendo la matriz y la va mostrando
def Pinta_Mapa():
    nX = nY = 0
    for nF in range(0, 9):
        for nC in range(0, 12):  # (x,y)
            Panta.blit(aSprt[mapa[nF][nC]], (nX, nY))
            nX += 44
        nY += 44
        nX = 0
    return
```

Esto es lo que tenía quizá ¿no estoy viendo algo obvio?

```
while lOK:
 cKey = pygame.key.get_pressed() # Se presiono alguna tecla?
 if cKey[pygame.K_ESCAPE] : lOK = False
 ev = pygame.event.get()
 for e in ev:
  if e.type == QUIT       : lOK = False
 Pinta_Mapa()
 pintarobot()

 pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit
```

este es el bucle que tengo en mi codigo es un bucle normal creo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

Lo que sucede es que en el fondo, todo se trata de dibujar, borrar y volver a dibujar. Piensa en la ventana de Pygame como una especie de lienzo. Si dibujas una vez y quieres dibujar devuelta con un fondo blanco en el mismo lienzo, primero deberás pintar de blanco lo anterior.

En conclusión: si, pintaste muchas veces la imagen.

#### Solución 1

Entre las soluciones está dibujar un fondo en cada fotograma:

```
def pintarobot():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    velocidady = 1
    while y != 352:
        Panta.blit([surface que actúa de fondo], (0, 0))
        Panta.blit(aSprt[5],(x,y))
        y = y + velocidady
```

#### Solución 2

Por otro lado, puedes pintar toda la ventana del color que quieras:

```
def pintarobot():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    velocidady = 1
    while y != 352:
        Panta.fill((0,0,0))
        Panta.blit(aSprt[5],(x,y))
        y = y + velocidady
```

#### Una recomendación

Leete este tutorial: https://www.pythonmania.net/es/2010/03/25/tutorial-pygame-2-ventana-e-imagenes/. Allí aclaran muchas cosas: entre ellas como debería ser el bucle e incluso describen un fallo similar al tuyo.

Te lo recomiendo ya que este while `while y != 352` te podría dejar de servir cuando, por ejemplo, empieces a trabajar con varias imagenes y necesites que todas se muevan "a la vez" y no una por una.

---

#### Edición

Gracias a la información que agregaste, puedo decirte que está pasando:

Los dibujos en la ventana no se actualizan hasta que se hace `pygame.display.flip()` o `pygame.display.update()`. Aparece solamente luego del bucle while donde mueves la imagen. Por lo que, por supuesto, la ventana no te mostrará la imagen moviendose, si no que te aparecerá al final.

Podría decirte "coloca pygame.display.flip() dentro del while en el que mueves el sprite" y solucionaría el problema actual. Pero quiero ir más allá. Si haces eso que puse entre comillas y quieras agregar más de una imagen moviendose aplicando ese mismo concepto, verás que se mueve una imagen, llega a su destino y desaparece. Luego aparece la otra y se mueve, llega y desaparece. Y eso no es lo que buscarías.

#### Procedimiento

El plan sería crear un bucle que haga lo siguiente:

1. Procesar los eventos
2. Mover los sprites "a la vez". En este caso, el "a la vez" significa mover un poquito cada imagen una por una a la velocidad correspondiente.
3. Dibujar las imagenes en las nuevas posiciones.
4. Usar pygame.display.flip() para mostrar las imagenes en pantalla.

#### Código de ejemplo

Hice un juego en el cual se generan dos imagenes con un gris aleatorio, una velocidad aleatoria y una posicion aleatoria y avanzan hasta la coordenada 400.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import random

# -----------
# Constantes
# -----------

SCREEN_WIDTH = 640
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480

# ------------------------------
# Funcion principal del juego
# ------------------------------

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

    # Imagen 1
    image1 = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
    image1.fill((random.randrange(256),)*3)

    image1_x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH)
    image1_y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    speed1 = random.randrange(5)
    
    # Imagen 2
    image2 = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
    image2.fill((random.randrange(256),)*3)

    image2_x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH)
    image2_y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    speed2 = random.randrange(5)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        
        # procesamos los eventos
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        # Movemos un poquito ambas imagenes
        if(image1_x < 400):
            image1_x += speed1

        if(image2_x < 400):
            image2_x += speed2

        # dibujamos el fondo y las imagenes.
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(image1, (image1_x, image1_y))
        screen.blit(image2, (image2_x, image2_y))

        # mostramos todo en pantalla
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Por supuesto, para evitar un código tan repetitivo se pueden usar diccionarios y bucles for o (mejor) programación orientada a objetos. Pero eso te toca aprenderlo a vos ;)

Comment: Gracias ^^ pero lo hice en mi código y no funciono, puede ser porque no tengo 1 sola imagen sino que tengo 12x9 de imágenes de 44x44?
Pero esta vez no se vio una animacion si no que quedo pintado al inicio y al final

Comment: Que raro que te haya quedado pintado dos veces. Podrías poner un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) del bucle de tu juego editando tu pregunta para ver que está fallando por favor? Por cierto, insisto en que revises el tutorial.

Comment: @user281196 está perfecta tu idea. El punto es "tapar" lo anterior, así que redibujar el fondo aunque esté compuesto de varias surfaces está bien. Sin embargo, no veo en el código que publicaste el bucle del juego. Ni siquiera un pygame.display.flip que actualize la ventana.

Comment: Buenas, leí el tutorial pero creo que es exactamente lo que estoy aplicando ahí o al menos eso entendí pero aún así no funciona

Comment: @user281196 Gracias! Agregué una parte extra a mi respuesta, ojalá te sirva c:

Comment: Gracias! Si lo entendí y me funciono ^^

Answer (score 0):

Esto de la estela es porque en pygame tienes que recargar cada fotograma, es decir, que tendrías que imprimir lo que tienes en el fondo cada fotograma, y antes de la imagen que quieras poner, porque en caso contrario saldrá el fondo por encima de la imagen y no será visible.